# Getting the line numbers of all undefined variables in Jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I am working on a configuration validation tool, where the configuration files are Jinja templates. One part of validation is to validate that all template variables are defined.

It seems that the only way to get the line number for an undefined variable in a Jinja template is to pass the StrictUndefined to the Environment and then read the line number from the stack trace when the exception gets raised.

However, this approach has the unfortunate consequence of StructUndefined raising the exception is that the parsing gets aborted when the parser encounters the first undefined variable, which means that the validation tool is not capable of validating the whole configuration file when a variable is undefined.

Does anyone know of a way to get the information on line number without raising exceptions?